# c++ customized map key/value not in order

Tags: c++, stl

I built the following map using a self-defined struct.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <map>

struct keys {
   int first;
   int second;
   int third;
};

struct keyCompare
{
   bool operator()(const keys& k1, const keys& k2) 
   {
    //return (k1.first<k2.first && k1.second<k2.second && k1.third<k2.third);
    return (k1.first<k2.first || k1.second<k2.second || k1.third<k2.third);
    //return (k1.first<k2.first || (k1.first==k2.first && k1.second<k2.second) || (k1.first==k2.first
    //  && k1.second==k2.second && k1.third<k2.third));
   }
};

int main()
{
   keys mk, mk1;
   int len = 4;
   //int myints1[9] = {1,2,3,4,5,6, 7,8,9};
   int myints1[12] = {1,2,3,4,5,6,1,2,3,1,2,3};
std::vector<int> input1(myints1, myints1+12);

std::map<keys, int, keyCompare> c2int;

for (int i = 0; i < len; i++) {
    mk.first = input1[i*3];
    mk.second = input1[i*3+1];
    mk.third = input1[i*3+2];
    c2int[mk] = i;
}

for (int i = 0; i < len;i++) {
    mk1.first = input1[i*3];
    mk1.second = input1[i*3+1];
    mk1.third = input1[i*3+2];
    std::cout << "map content " << c2int[mk1] << "\n";
}

return 0;}
```

The code works as expected for non-repeated keys like {1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9}. The return is

```
map content is 0
map content is 1
map content is 2
```

but when there are repeated patterns, e.g., keys are {1,2,3,4,5,6,1,2,3}. The print out is

```
map content is 2
map content is 1
map content is 2
```

while I was expecting

```
map content is 0
map content is 1
map content is 0
```

since key {1,2,3} has already assigned value 0. But the compare function seems modify this key to value 2 instead of 0. I tried different compare function but none of them shows expected output. I think I had missed something in this approach. Can someone explain? Thanks

Comment: Compare the first value, but if they are equal then compare the second value. If second value is also equal, then compare the third value. If you make the key a tuple, it should do this automatically.

Comment: You're comparator violates [strict weak ordering](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Weak_ordering#Strict_weak_orderings), which is mandated for ordered associative containers in the standard library. Something like `return std::tie(k1.first,k1.second,k1.third) < std::tie(k2.first, k2.second, k2.third);`

Comment: I think my commented out lines in compare function does what you meant. No?

Comment: @iis The third version looks right, see my answer for a different way of writing it.

Comment: std::tie is for c++11? I don't have c++11 compiler here

Comment: If you use your third option (which appears closer to correct) you understand your `c2int[mk] = i;` is *overwriting* the value when a like-key is encountered, right? If that isn't what you want (replacement) then perhaps `c2int.insert(std::make_pair(mk, i));` is more what you seek (with the right comparator, of course).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This comparator is incorrect:

```
bool operator()(const keys& k1, const keys& k2) 
{
 return (k1.first<k2.first || k1.second<k2.second || k1.third<k2.third);
}
```

Consider `{1,4,9}` vs `{2,3,4}`. `{1,4,9} < {2,3,4}` because of the first comparison, but then `{2,3,4} < {1,4,9}` because of the second! That's clearly not what you intended! Besides, `operator<` must be asymmetric in order to be a [StrictWeakOrdering](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Weak_ordering#Strict_weak_orderings), which is what is required for `std::map`.

You have to deal with the keys in order:

```
bool operator()(const keys& k1, const keys& k2) {
    if (k1.first != k2.first) {
        return k1.first < k2.first;
    }
    else if (k1.second != k2.second) {
        return k1.second < k2.second;
    }
    else {
        return k1.third < k2.third;
    }
}
```

Comment: thanks for pointing out the strict weak ordering rule. but I still can't get my expected outcome with your compare function. something else wrong?

Comment: @iis What is your expected outcome? Looks like it's doing the right thing to me once you fix the comparator. You're adding 4 things into your map, but 3 of them have the same key (`{1,2,3}`), so you end up with a map of size 2. It prints 3, 1, 3, 3... which is what I'd expect.

Comment: i expected the value of 3 identical keys is 0. I got a size of 2 map. I don't know why these 3 keys has value greater than {4,5,6}

Comment: To add: key {4,5,6} has always value 1, which is I expected. key {1,2,3} should have value 0, shouldn't it?

Comment: @iis No, you initially insert it with value 0, but then you overwrite it to 2 (in the 3rd iteration of the loop) and then to 3 (in the 4th). If you don't want to overwrite, you should use [`insert`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/map/insert) instead of [`operator[]`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/map/operator_at).

Comment: @iis use `c2int.insert(std::make_pair(mk, i));` instead of `c2int[mk] = i;`, and of course, fix your comparator.

Comment: viola, insert is the answer! yes, I don't want to the value be overwritten. thanks a lot :-)

Comment: @iis worth your time to look up how [`std::map<>::insert`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/map/insert) works. Glad to help.

Answer (score 0):

Your `keyCompare` is not valid for a `std::map`.

It needs to return `true` for `(a,b)` if `a` should be ordered before `b`.

You have written a function that could return true for `(a,b)` **and** `(b,a)`.  This violates [strict weak ordering](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Weak_ordering#Strict_weak_orderings).